# 'await' does not return, when my Task is started from a custom TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

**Background:**

I have a "Messenger" class.  It sends messages.  But due to limitations, let's say it can only send - at most - ***5*** messages at a time.

I have a WPF application which queues messages as needed, and waits for the queued message to be handled before continuing.  Due to the asynchronous nature of the application, any number of messages could be `await`ed at any given time.

**Current Implementation:**

To accomplish this, I've implemented a `Task<Result> SendMessage(Message message)` API within my messaging class.  Internal to the messaging class is a custom TaskScheduler (the [LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), with its concurrency level set to 5.  In this way, I would expect that no matter how many messages are queued, only 5 will be sent out at a time, and my client application will patiently wait until its respective message has been handled.

**Problem:**

When I `await` the `SendMessage` method, I can see via the debugger that the message was completed and the result returned, but my code never executes beyond the `await`ed method call!

Is there some special considerations that need to be made, when `await`ing a Task which was scheduled using a different TaskScheduler?

**Snipped Code:**

From my client/consuming function:

```
public async Task Frobulate()
{
    Message myMessage = new Message(x, y, z);
    await messenger.SendMessage(myMessage);

    //Code down here never executes!
}
```

From my messenger class:

```
private TaskScheduler _messengerTaskScheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(5);
private TaskFactory _messengerTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(_messengerScheduler);

public Task<Result> SendMessage(Message message)
{
    //My debugger has verified that "InternalSendMessage" has completed, 
    //but the caller's continuation appears to never execute
    return _messengerTaskFactory.StartNew(() => InternalSendMessage(message));
}
```

**Update:**

The 'freeze' does not actually appear to be caused by my custom `TaskScheduler`; when I queue up the `Task` with the default `TaskFactory`, the same behavior occurs!  There must be something else happening at a more fundamental level, likely due to my own stupidity.

Comment: Should be fine... can you reproduce this in a short but complete program? Is your awaiting code *also* running in the limited concurrency scheduler?

Comment: Why use a `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` to limit to 5 messages instead of using a `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`?

Comment: Are you sure `SendMessage` properly finishes? No exceptions from the completed `Task`?

Comment: I am sure that `SendMessageInternal` property finishes.  After that, I can also step through and see my TaskScheduler decrementing the count of queued delegates... but I am not sure what happens after that.

Comment: The SemaphoreSlim seems like a cleaner, shorter, less-complicated approach.  Why would I want to do that?  Actually, I may switch to that approach in the name of completing my task, but now I would also really like to find out what went wrong with my async/await code.

Comment: Could you add the code for `InternalSendMessage`?

Comment: @BTownTKD, do you use `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait()` anywhere in your code? If so, it can be the popular deadlock scenario: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: I think you've found the issue.  There was actually a series of nesting async/await function calls, and at the *very* top of the stack is a call to Task.Result.  I will try this and report back.  Please do post this as a potential answer, so I can give credit.

Comment: @BTownTKD, the credit should go to Stephen Cleary, but feel free to post your own answer, I'd up-vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, you probably have a deadlock because you're blocking on async code.

When using async, whenever there are thread restrictions on the `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler` and the code blocks using `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait` there's a possibility of deadlocking. The asynchronous operation needs a thread to finish execution, which it can't get because the `SynchronizationContext` (or `TaskScheduler` in your case) is waiting for that *same exact* operation to complete before allowing "new" ones to run.

Go deeper in Stephen Cleary's blog post: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)